# MS Access, getting total values from two tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am trying to get the total values from tables "sales" and "payment" where the customer_id in both tables match the customer selected from a combo box in a form.

Table 1: Sales

```
customer_id item    item_value
1           Fan     $200
3           AC      $500
1           Iron    $50
```

Table 2: Payment

```
customer_id amount
1           $150
2           $300
1           $50
4           $100
```

I am not sure how to write a query to get the following result:

Query Result

```
customer_id total_purchase_amount   total_paid_amount
1           250                     $200
```

Your help is appreciated!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use correlated subquery :

```
select s.customer_id, sum(s.item_value) as total_purchase_amount,
       (select sum(p.amount) 
        from Payment p 
        where p.customer_id = s.customer_id
       ) as total_paid_amount
from Sales s
where s.customer_id = ? -- you can pass here customer_id
group by s.customer_id;
```

Comment: Perfect answer... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can join the two summed tables, e.g.:

```
select a.customer_id, a.total_purchase_amount, b.total_paid_amount
from
    (
        select s.customer_id, sum(s.item_value) as total_purchase_amount
        from sales s
        group by s.customer_id
    ) a left join
    (
        select p.customer_id, sum(p.amount) as total_paid_amount
        from payment p
        group by p.customer_id
    ) b on a.customer_id = b.customer_id
```

To filter by a customer selected from your combo box, you might include a `where` clause such as:

```
where a.customer_id = Forms!YourForm!YourComboBox
```

You may also want to use `Nz(b.total_paid_amount, 0)` to show zero for those customers with no `Payment` records.